# threads with BackgroudWorker, waits a long time . How can i avoid this

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, backgroundworker

I am using thread with `BackgroundWorker` by this, the application is waiting for a long time to fetch 50000 records, it makes the other operation to wait until this thread completes. How can I avoid the waiting process while using the secondary thread.

```
private void btnExrtPDF_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DetailsOrSummary == "Details")
        isDetails = true;

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            DetailReportFCBuySell = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(
                transactionName, isDetails,
                Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date,
                Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date,
                Customerid, ProductID, branchID,
                NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch
        {            
            object obj = new object(); 
        }
    }));
}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{        
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        System.Data.DataTable batchFCSB = new System.Data.DataTable();
        int row = 0;

        if (DetailReportFCBuySell.FirstOrDefault().TotalRecords > toFetchRecords)
        {
            long RecordsIcrease = 1000;
            batchFCSB = DetailReportFCBuySell.ToDataTable();
            //Collection.Add(row, batchFCSB);
            row = 1;
            PageIndex++;

            for (long k = toFetchRecords; k < DetailReportFCBuySell.FirstOrDefault().TotalRecords; k = +toFetchRecords)
            {
                new AlxServiceClient().Using(channel =>
                {
                    ObservableCollection<DLReports.FCBuySellDetail> temp
                        = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(
                            transactionName, isDetails,
                            Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date,
                            Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date,
                            Customerid, ProductID, branchID, NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);

                    DetailReportFCBuySell = DetailReportFCBuySell.Union(temp).ToObservableCollection();

                    row++;
                    PageIndex++;

                });
                toFetchRecords = toFetchRecords + RecordsIcrease;
            }
        }
    }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
}
```

Comment: Just ensure that updating the UI components and manipulating the observable collection is done on the UI thread. Currently you're executing everything on the UI thread.

Comment: s already the pblm resolved by me, thanks for ur responce for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is completely wrong. You should not have either of those calls to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` or `Dispatcher.Invoke()`. The call to `BeginInvoke()` is pointless, achieving nothing useful, and the latter is causing all of the work to actually be done in the UI thread instead of in the background worker thread where it belongs.

There are more modern approaches you can use instead of `BackgroundWorker`, like `await Task.Run(...)`. And without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to suggest anything more specific. But as the code you posted stands now, if you would just remove all the calls to the `Dispatcher` methods and execute the invoked code directly, it should work as you expect.

Comment: If i remove all the calls of dispactcher ( it shows "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."). ( and one more thing is am first time using the backgroundworker and thread in my application. so from the examples shown from stackOverflow i do this much ,sir)

Comment: Without a good [mcve], I can't tell what's a UI object and what's not, and so can't provide any more specific advice than the above. It's true that when you access UI objects, you'll have to use `Dispatcher.Invoke()` or similar to do so. But the rest of the code needs to operate in the background thread; wrapping the _entire_ task in a call to `Dispatcher.Invoke()` isn't correct and completely negates the point of using `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: The question you asked here is about why your `BackgroundWorker` running blocks the UI thread, and this answer addresses that. If after resolving that issue, you still can't figure out how to correctly update the UI objects, please post a new question and this time make sure you've included a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can use a background worker.

[image: Sample app]

Add 2 buttons to a WinForm.

First btnStartWorker triggers the background worker.

While btnStartWorker is disabled and the background worker is running, btnOther can still be clicked.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private delegate void ReenableDelegate();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private BackgroundWorker worker;
    private void btnStartWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStartWorker.Enabled = false;

        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        Thread.Sleep(5000); // simulate long running operation here
    }

    private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new ReenableDelegate(Enable));
    }

    private void Enable()
    {
        btnStartWorker.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btnOther_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Doing other stuff");
    }
}
```

Comment: no only one task , this method i tried but , the UI is waiting for some time

Comment: when you say waiting, do you mean blocking?

Comment: s, UI will not work until this thread complete. i need to work UI while this thread works parallely